# Attach values to elements of a List in Java

Tags: java, list, oop, arraylist, collections

I've a list of integers from which I counted repetitions and printed those out using a map. Now each of those integers in the `Items` list has to have a certain value to be assigned to them.

My output is :

```
2 x 3

8 x 1
```

Eventually what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
2 x 3 $5.50

8 x 1 $12.50

Total = $29
```

which means integer 2 and 8 each have a value, say $5.50 and $12.50 respectively.

1. What would be the best way in Java to assign a value to the integers in this list?
2. How can I handle the calculation?

The program takes in orders for bakery items - total quantity along with codes as input . E.g 14 Muffins. And each item has a set of packages available (say 2,5,8) each with it's cost. I used the coin change algorithm to breakdown 14 muffins in the packs available.

e.g Input = 14 Muffins

Expected Output:

14 Muffins $54.8

1 x 8 $24.95

3 x 2 $9.95

I've done the package breakdown using the coin change algorithm, now I'm in pursuit of best ways to setup an OO design to achieve the output. I would highly appreciate any suggestions on this.

Here's my code to get duplicates from the list:

```
public static void packagesprint() {
        List<Integer> items = Arrays.asList(8, 2, 2, 2);

        Map<Integer, Long> result = items.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Long> entry : result.entrySet())
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " x "+
                    + entry.getValue());    
    }
```

Outputs:

```
2x3

8x1
```

Comment: actually, in any logic case, Integer 2 has value 2. I assume a better approach would be to create a composite object whose Id = 2 and has a value of $5.50

Comment: Why `2x3(5.50) + 8x1(12.50) = 28` ? `5.5*3 + 12.5 = 29`, isn't?

Comment: @Alessandro: my bad. edited the mistake

Comment: Whers is stored the association `2=5.50$`, `8=12.50$`, etc... ?

Comment: @Alessandro: I haven't stored anywhere yet. A part of my question basically is to get the best suggestion on how to handle that. So far I've used a coin change algorithm to break down a value into it'd denominations. Now each of those denominations will need to have a value to be assigned. What are you suggestions on that?

Comment: how will you know which is which? example ```2x3```, how will you know which digits will be replaced?

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing the whole architecture, anyway you could take a look to the `HashMap` class. Ex: `map.put(2, 5.5)`;

Comment: @Alessandro The program takes in orders for bakery items - total quantity along with codes as input .
E.g 10 Muffins. And each item has a set of packages available (say 2,5,8) each with it's cost. I used the coin change algorithm to breakdown 10 muffins in the packs available. 

e.g Input = 10 Muffins

Expected Output: 

14 Muffins $54.8
1 x 8 $24.95
3 x 2 $9.95

I've the package breakdown from the algorithm, now I'm in pursuit of best ways to setup an OO design to achieve the output. I would highly appreciate any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible ways to approach that problem. I will present you a few possibilities.

1. First possible way is to make a new Object which contains key ,value and number of duplicates. This is a good approach since you have all the needed data in one object.

Refer below for the implementation:

```
public class MyObject{
    private int id;
    private double value;
    private int numberOfDuplicates;

    public MyObject(){
        this.id = 0;
        this.value = 0;
        this.numberOfDuplicates = 0;    
    }

    public MyObject(int id, double value, int numberOfDuplicates){
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
        this.numberOfDuplicates = numberOfDuplicates;    
    }

    // INSERT GETTERS AND SETTERS BELOW
}
```

Then you will use it this way:

```
public static void packagesprint() {
        List<Integer> items = Arrays.asList(8, 2, 2, 2);
        List<MyObject> myObjectList =  ArrayList<>();

        Map<Integer, Long> result = items.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Long> entry : result.entrySet()){
            MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
            myObject.setId(entry.getKey());
            myObject.setNumberOfDuplicates(entry.getValue().intValue()); 
            myObject.setValue(value); // <- this is where you set your value, e.g. if 2's value is 5.50, then set 5.50 as value 
            myObjectList.add(myObject);
        }

}
```

2. Another possible approach is that you can use `HashMap` and set `2` as key and "5.50" as value. A downside of this approach is that you will still have to search the value for the number of duplicates in another map (in your case the `result` map).

Refer below for the implementation:

```
public static void packagesprint() {
        List<Integer> items = Arrays.asList(8, 2, 2, 2);
        Map<Integer, Double> keyValuePairs = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();

        Map<Integer, Long> result = items.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Long> entry : result.entrySet()){
            keyValuePairs.put(entry.getKey(), value) // <- this is where you set your value, e.g. if 2's value is 5.50, then set 5.50 as value 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like some sort of a shopping card. I would use a catalogue of products (that could be stored in a database):

```
public class Catalogue {
    public Product getProductById(int id) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String label;
    private double price;
    // ...

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And I would define a class `Order` that would be a collection of `OrderItem`. each item being a quantity and a product. To group the items in the order, you can use a map with the product id as the key:

```
public class OrderItem {
    private int quantity;
    private Product product;

    public OrderItem(int quantity, Product product) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.product = product;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return quantity*product.getPrice();
    }
}

public class Order {
    private final Map<Integer,OrderItem> items = new HashMap<>();

    public Iterable<OrderItem> getItems() {
        return new ArrayList<>(items.values());
    }

    public void add(int quantity, Product product) {
        OrderItem item = items.get(product.getId());
        if (item != null) {
            item.setQuantity(item.getQuantity() + quantity);
        } else {
            items.put(product.getId(), new OrderItem(quantity, product));
        }
    }

    public void add(Product product) {
        add(1, product);
    }

    public void add(OrderItem item) {
        add(item.getQuantity(), item.getProduct());
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        double total = 0;
        for (OrderItem item: items.values()) {
            total += item.getAmount();
        }
        return total;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now you can build your order from a list of product ids as follows:

```
    List<Integer> items = Arrays.asList(8, 2, 2, 2);
    Order order = new Order();
    for (int id: items) {
        order.add(catalogue.getProductById(id));
    }
```

And then calculate the total with `getTotal()`:

```
    System.out.println(order.getTotal());
```

Comment: Thank you Maurice. The program takes in orders for bakery items - total quantity along with codes as input . E.g 10 Muffins. And each item has a set of packages available (say 2,5,8) each with it's cost. I used the coin change algorithm to breakdown 10 muffins in the packs available. e.g Input = 10 Muffins Expected Output: 14 Muffins $54.8 1 x 8 $24.95 3 x 2 $9.95. I've the package breakdown from the algorithm, now I'm in pursuit of best ways to setup an OO design to achieve the output.

Comment: I've edited the description of my problem above for a better explanation of the expected output

Comment: OK, So if I understand you correctly, if you want n muffins, the program must give the breakdown for a total of at least n muffins, that has the minimal cost?

Comment: No, I don't understand: to have 10 muffins, I would need a pack of 8 plus a pack of 2, wouldn't I?

Comment: The program does not have to optimize the cost. It has to to breakdown the total in terms of available packages for that item and return any combination that matches the total order along with the cost.  Sorry there is a typo in my comment above, i have fixed it the problem description above . It's 14 muffins. I mistakenly wrote 10.

Comment: A problem I see in your example is that you can't get an odd number of muffins. So how should we deal with this case? should we provide at least the number of muffins requested? in that case, I have another problem: I can get 14 muffins for $54.80, or 16 (2x8) muffins for $49.90 !!!

Comment: Yes you're  right. I initially went on to solve this using knapsack. Then I was told not to worry about optimizing the total cost. So it's more about providing the number of muffins required. Now with the algorithm in place to provide the pack breakdown, my challenge right now is the OO design to handle this and how to print the output with values. There are 3 kinds of items in total, each having their unique codes(Muffins , Pies , Cakes) and respective package sizes. (e.g Muffins available in packs on 2,5; Pies in packs of 2,5,8 and so on).